Weird Rheem Gas Hot Water Heater Thermostat Issue
I have a weird issue with my old gas Rheem hot water heater (Model PROG48-40U) that I'm hoping someone can help me with. My Rheem gas hot water heater burner won't fire until I turn on the a hot water tap in my house. Once I turn on the hot water (like the shower) the burner will turn on and heat the water to a sufficiently hot temperature. But after the water comes to temperature my hot water heater burner won't fire again until I turn on the hot water somewhere in my house. The hot water in the boiler will just cool to a tepid temperature and the thermostat won't kick in (that is until I turn on a hot water tap).
The pilot flame stays on (no issues there). Each morning I turn on the hot water on my faucet, then the burner will kick in, and 20 minutes later I have piping hot water. I called Rheem and they advised I should replace the gas control valve (it's an older style Rheem White-Rodgers Gas Control Thermostat). Could it be possible that it's something else wrong? I recently replaced the entire burner assembly and was trouble free for a couple of weeks until now.
It's weird that the thermostat and burner trigger but only when I turn on the hot water (like in a faucet or shower). Anyone have any ideas other than replacing the gas control thermostat or replacing the entire hot water heater? As always, any advice is appreciated.

